# Getting an iOS app to work with AWS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am just getting started with using AWS inside an iOS app, as a server backend.
After following the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html), I am now hitting this issue, having the message below in the debugger:

**CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:ListTables on resource: ***

Searching the net has driven me to a number of posts, but none of them has been clear enough to help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't grant permissions to the role that Cognito assumes. See "Set Permissions" of this guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html. Learn more about IAM roles here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html.